# Why is "Cat" not working in my C-shell that I built?

Tags: c, shell, fork, wait

When I type Cat hello.txt for example, it just reads Cat and starts almost an inner loop and everything I type is just repeated. single commands such as "ls" work fine. I think it has to do with there being a space. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];
    int loop = 1;
    int pid;
    int status;
    char *cmd;

    while (1)
    {
        status = 0;

        printf("Ben$ ");
        // printf("%d\n",pid );
        if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin))
        {
            loop = 0;
            break;
        }
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {

            if ((cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS)))
            {
                // Clear errors
                errno = 0;

                if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0)
                {
                    char *arg = strtok(0, DELIMS);

                    if (!arg)
                        fprintf(stderr, "cd missing argument.\n");
                    else
                        chdir(arg);

                }
                else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0)
                {
                    _Exit(3);
                    printf("should have exited\n");

                }
                else
                {
                    char *name[] = {
                        "/bin/bash",
                        "-c",
                        line, NULL
                    };
                    execvp(name[0], name);

                }

                if (errno)
                    perror("Command failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // printf("%d\n",pid );
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

            if (status != 0)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `exec`'ing bash? Why not just `exec` the command the user entered directly?

Comment: I'm running this ontop of a shell and I need bash to run the commands I think

Comment: As a shell, you're supposed to implement command-line processing yourself, not just pawn it off to another shell (like bash).

Comment: so instead of using bash, how would I accomplish "ls" for example

Comment: By forking and exec'ing the `ls` command, not by invoking `bash` to execute it for you.

Comment: e.g. something like this? execl("/usr/bin/", "ls");

Comment: ah ok. I'm on my way to getting this to work. I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `strtok`, which "breaks up" a string by replacing the first of the delimiter characters with a `'\0'`.  So, if `line` has this before the `strtok` call:

```
{ 'c', 'a', 't', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',
  '.', 't', 'x', 't', '\n', '\0', <junk...> }
```

then it has this in it afterward:

```
{ 'c', 'a', 't', '\0', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',
  '.', 't', 'x', 't', '\n', '\0', <junk...> }
```

Thus, you invoke `"/bin/bash"` with `"-c"`, `"cat"`, `NULL`.

Aside: the variable `loop` is not tested; in a shell, `cd` and `exit` commands must be implemented in the parent, not after a `fork` call; and as @shanet noted, you could just `execvp` the command directly (for non-pipeline, no redirection) commands, though you will have to split up the arguments first.  (Real shells need to do their own file and pipe handling as well, but obviously that's something for later. :-) )

Comment: I will have to try that. cd is working as is no problem. Why should I move it before the fork?